# How to label text alternative for synchronized media in WCAG 2.0 SC 1.2.2

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

According to WCAG 2.0 success criterion 1.2.2:

> 1.2.2 Captions (Prerecorded) Level A
>
> Captions are provided for all prerecorded audio content in
>   synchronized media, except when the media is a media alternative for
>   text and is clearly labeled as such.

I have an HTML construct that falls under the exception to the success criterion, that is, the HTML that precedes the video is already a text alternative for the video. Consider the following:

```html
<p>
  some explanatory text for the video
</p>
<p>
  another block of explanation
  <img src="./my-image.png" alt="alt for image" />
</p>
<p>
  <video>
    <source src="./my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</p>
```

SC 1.2.2 describes a failure to label the text alternative in https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F74.html but it does not describe how to properly label the video to point to that text alternative.

One possible solution is to wrap my explanatory text within a `<div>` containing an `id` attribute, and then use `aria-describedby` in the video tag pointing to this `id`. Something like:

```html
<div id="my-explanation">
  <p>
    my explanatory text...
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <video aria-describedby="my-explanation">
    ...
  </video>
</p>
```

My questions are: would this technique conform to the requirements of the success criterion? Would there be another technique commonly used to label a block of html as a text alternative to synchronized media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aria-describedby` seems perfectly appropriate. You can also use a `<track ...>` element with suitable `kind` attribute (subtitles, captions, descriptions, chapters)

See for instance [H95: Using the track element to provide captions](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H95.html)

or [the `<track>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-track-element) in the HTML5 documentation

According to [Techniques for WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/)

> Techniques are informative—that means they are not required.

This means that as long as you achieve the intent of the guideline, no matter the technique you use, this should be perfectly ok.